# $wpdb->get_row() only returns a single row?

Tags: wpdb

Why is it? I tried the same query in the console and it returned multiple rows. Here's the query:

`$this->wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$this->wpdb->users." WHERE status = 'active'", ARRAY_A);`

It keeps returning the same single row when there are several active users. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's called `get_row()` for a reason...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Indeed, use `get_row()` only when you expect to get one result, else you can use `get_results()`

Comment: For reference see
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/
and
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Answer (score 58):

There are three ways to pull data from the database.

1.`$wpdb->get_var`:use this to get a single value from the database table. Like if you want to count the total number of comments. You can do it in following way:

```
<?php 
$comment_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments;")); 
echo '<p>Total comments: ' . $comment_count . '</p>';
?>
```

2.`$wpdb->get_row` : To retrieve an entire table row you can use this.

**Example:**

```
<?php 
$thepost = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = 1" ) );
echo $thepost->post_title; 
?>
```

OR

```
<?php 
$thepost = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = 1" ), ARRAY_A );
print_r ($thepost); 
?>
```

By using the `ARRAY_A` parameter in get_row your post data is returned as an associative array. Alternatively, you could use the `ARRAY_N` parameter to return your post data in a numerically indexed array.

3.`$wpdb->get_results`:Standard `SELECT` queries should use the get_results function for retrieving multiple rows of data from the database.

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$allposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'") );
foreach ($allposts as $singlepost) { 
         echo '<p>' .$singlepost->post_title. '</p>';
}
?>
```

**and you need the last one, as you can expect.**

Comment: Wonderful detail examples..

Comment: Sure! why not..

Comment: Really great examples. For speed optimisation in last example I will recommend change this: `($allposts as $singlepost)` to: `($allposts as $k => $singlepost)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$wpdb->get_row('query', output_type, row_offset);
```

row_offset 
(integer) The desired row (0 being the first). Defaults to 0.

va http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

my solution is simple..

```
<?php
function count_results() {
    # use the data base
    global $wpdb;

    # Query to count all results from one table
    $sql_count_results = '
        SELECT count(*) as count
        FROM `YOUR_TABLE`;';

    # Ejecute function
    $results = $wpdb->get_row( $sql_count_results , OBJECT );

    # Return results
    return $results->count;
}
```

Use:

```
<?php
echo count_results();
```

Comment: It would be great if you can also explain what this code does in addtion to posting it.

Comment: This counts the rows in a table, it is not an answer to the OP's question.